# throwing error while importing pymysql in Python code

Tags: import, pymysql

I am working in machine in which python 3.6 is installed on windows 7

I cross validated pymysql installation.

pip3 install PyMySQL
Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in c:\users\

But still in the code, its throwing error while importing pymysql.

```
import pymysql
```

error detail:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check if the installation was done correctly

If you are not able to install it properly you could download the gzip or the wheel and do a pip install of that gzip or the wheel

Both are available here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL